# Need help to optimize MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

**I have 6 tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbpr_groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `dnd` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbpr_newsletter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `from` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `attach1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `attach2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `attach3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=14;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbpr_news_groups` (
  `newsletter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `groups` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fk_sbpr_news_groups_sbpr_newsletter1` (`newsletter_id`),
  KEY `fk_sbpr_news_groups_sbpr_groups1` (`groups`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbpr_news_recs` (
  `newsletter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipients` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fk_sbpr_news_recs_sbpr_newsletter1` (`newsletter_id`),
  KEY `fk_sbpr_news_recs_sbpr_recipients1` (`recipients`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbpr_recipients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mail` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_reg` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3008 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbpr_rec_groups` (
  `rec_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fk_sbpr_rec_groups_sbpr_recipients` (`rec_id`),
  KEY `fk_sbpr_rec_groups_sbpr_groups1` (`group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**With this foreign keys:**

```
ALTER TABLE `sbpr_news_groups`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sbpr_news_groups_sbpr_groups1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`groups`) REFERENCES `sbpr_groups` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sbpr_news_groups_sbpr_newsletter1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`newsletter_id`) REFERENCES `sbpr_newsletter` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `sbpr_news_recs`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sbpr_news_recs_sbpr_newsletter1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`newsletter_id`) REFERENCES `sbpr_newsletter` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sbpr_news_recs_sbpr_recipients1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`recipients`) REFERENCES `sbpr_recipients` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `sbpr_rec_groups`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sbpr_rec_groups_sbpr_groups1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`group`) REFERENCES `sbpr_groups` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sbpr_rec_groups_sbpr_recipients` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`rec_id`) REFERENCES `sbpr_recipients` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

**Visual structure of tables:**
[image]

I want to select all rows from **sbpr_newsletter** table, and add to each of these lines the number of rows from **sbpr_recipients** whose id prescribed in **sbpr_news_recs** or prescribed in **sbpr_rec_groups** depends on FKs.

Ex. I want to select count of all recipients of current newsletter wihch are in **sbpr_news_recs** or exists in group which are in **sbpr_rec_groups** plus count of active recipients.

**I have working SQL:**

```
SELECT d.id,  d.subject , d.created_date,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM sbpr_recipients r
      LEFT JOIN sbpr_news_recs nr ON nr.recipients = r.id
      LEFT JOIN sbpr_rec_groups g ON g.rec_id = r.id
      LEFT JOIN sbpr_news_groups ng ON ng.groups = g.group
      WHERE nr.newsletter_id = d.id OR ng.newsletter_id = d.id) AS repicients,

    (SELECT count(*) FROM sbpr_recipients r
      LEFT JOIN sbpr_news_recs nr ON nr.recipients = r.id
      LEFT JOIN sbpr_rec_groups g ON g.rec_id = r.id
      LEFT JOIN sbpr_news_groups ng ON ng.groups = g.group
      WHERE (nr.newsletter_id = d.id OR ng.newsletter_id = d.id) 
      AND r.active = 1) AS active_repicients
FROM sbpr_newsletter d
ORDER BY d.id ASC, d.id
```

**Explain of this sql:**
[image]

**Question:**
How can I optimize my sql?

Comment: +1 for all the detail.  Wish more questions were like this.

Comment: What does your explain look like when you change `order by d.id ASC, d.id` to `order by d.id ASC`?

Comment: @ARTstudio This looks good: the "filesort" is gone. How slow is your query now? Can you do this again with `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ...` if your MySQL version supports that.

Comment: @eisberg the same 3 rows fetched in 0:00.1040 sec EXPLAIN EXTENDED: http://imm.io/4YVt

Comment: ditto the comment from Wes - great question with great info. A problem well explained is a problem half solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just approach to optimize, two SELECT queries are transfered into JOIN clause -

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.subject
     , d.created_date
     , count(if(nr_newsletter_id is not null or ng_newsletter_id is not null, 1, null)) repicients
     , count(if((nr_newsletter_id is not null or ng_newsletter_id is not null) and t.active = 1, 1, null)) active_repicients
FROM
  sbpr_newsletter d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT nr.newsletter_id nr_newsletter_id
       , ng.newsletter_id ng_newsletter_id
       , r.active
  FROM
    sbpr_recipients r
  LEFT JOIN sbpr_news_recs nr
    ON nr.recipients = r.id
  LEFT JOIN sbpr_rec_groups g
    ON g.rec_id = r.id
  LEFT JOIN sbpr_news_groups ng
    ON ng.groups = g.group
  ) t
ON nr_newsletter_id = d.id OR ng_newsletter_id = d.id
GROUP BY
  d.id;
```

I rewrited your query a little, it is not tested, but try it.

Comment: Very nice! It executes twice faster than my variant.

Comment: I just noticed thet results of your query and my is different: http://imm.io/4YWf

Comment: I think some conditions should be added into COUNT functions. The rows should be counted only when nr_newsletter_id is not null or ng_newsletter_id is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD create a view and query that instead - trade off is storage but should vastly remove load from server...

Answer (score 0):

The subquery for recipients / active_recipients runs twice, and each time returns 3311 records, so it would be worth defining as a view.

Otherwise, define indexes on the foreign keys you use in joins.

Comment: Query from @Devart executes in the same time with indexes and without them, did I still need to add indexes?